# eclipse doesn't see java file generated during installation of maven module

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, import

I am working on a specific maven module. I have it imported into eclipse by m2eclipse plugin. The module uses our internal plugin to generate java files from some csv files. During install goal those files are being generated and put to target/generated-sources/folder_name.
 
Can you tell me how I can import these java files into eclipse so it stops showing me compilation errors saying that 'x' cannot be resolved to a type? 

Now every module which uses those files has compilations errors in eclipse, everything works fine when I try to build from command line.
Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:** Thanks a lot guys, I was trying similar solution but instead of adding source folder I was trying to add external classes :|

Answer (score 2):

project -> properties -> java build path -> source -> add folder -> (search for target/generated-sources/folder_name, create it if deleted by maven) -> ok

now eclipse will only complain when you'll use `mvn clean` deleting target folder.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse refreshes file content on request, so any change made external to eclipse, eclipse doesn't know about that

You can make eclipse to use native hooks to detect external changes

```
preference > workspace > check refresh using native hooks
```

and add that directory to source path

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to add the folder of the generated files as a Source folder in the project. Look in the Project Properties > Java Build Path > Source tab and add the folder.